# Finding number of rows in each GROUP BY result

Tags: sql, database, group-by

I have a database the tells each systems current and new model. (Each row has a system name, current model, and new model) I need to group the results by the current model and new model. So if the current and new model are the same i want one result. I got that to work but i also need to know how many systems are in each group. How can I do that? Im using CI

This is my query

```
$query2 = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM rollout_systems WHERE scope_ID = '.$id.'  GROUP BY EAM_Model, new_Model');
```

(EAM_Model = current model)

Don't know if i clarified enough. I need to be able to display the Current System, the New System, and the number of systems in that group.

So if 3 rows have "blah" as there current system and "blahblah" as there new system, i want it to say
Current: Blah
New: Blah Blah
number of systems: 3

Comment: `SELECT *....GROUP BY field1, field2` is nonsense.  What are you trying to get exactly?

Comment: in rollout_systems there is a list of systems. each row (system) has a current model and a new model. I want to make it so if two or more rows have the same current AND new model they group. But i also need to know how many rows (systems) are in each group

Comment: You need to pick which fields you want to see, then.  You really should just read about how aggregation actually works.  I think you are confused about how `GROUP` operates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to do a select * and a group by in the same statement.  The columns you group by need to be in your select but then you should have an aggregate function like count(*) in your select.  I'm not sure I totally understand what you are trying to do, but I think you want something like:

```
SELECT EAM_Model, new_Model, count(*)
FROM rollout_systems 
WHERE scope_ID = '.$id.'              
GROUP BY EAM_Model, new_Model
```

Comment: But would the results for this tell me the current and new model and the number of rows in the group?

Comment: Yes, it will return the EAM_Model | new_Model | row_count

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the number of items, use `SELECT EAM_Model, new_Model, COUNT(*) FROM` ... etc.  When you group a query, you normally want to be performing an aggregate like COUNT or SUM or else it doesn't make sense to be grouping the data.

Answer (score 0):

$query2 = $this->db->query('SELECT **count(*)** FROM rollout_systems WHERE scope_ID = '.$id.'              GROUP BY EAM_Model, new_Model');

Is it this you are asking for?